# How do I type a JS file in node_modules?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, .d.ts

I installed module `foo` which has this `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "exports": {
    ".": ["./index.js"]
  },
  "types": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

`foo` comes with its own types for the module entry point. However, I need to import `bar.js` from `foo`. Because it isn't exported in `index.js`, I have to do this:

```
import {bar} from './node_modules/foo/bar'
```

This is because if I use `import bar from 'foo/bar'`, I get the error `Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './bar' is not defined by "exports" in /path/to/project/node_modules/foo/package.json`.

I have typed `foo/bar` like this:

```
export const bar: 'bar'
```

Where would I put this file and what will I need to put in my `tsconfig.json`?

---

I've already tried putting my typings in `./types/foo/bar.d.ts` and using `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./types"]` in my tsconfig `compilerOptions`, but TS couldn't find my declaration file:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module './node_modules/foo/bar'. '/path/to/project/node_modules/foo/bar.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I've also tried `/// <reference types="./types/foo/bar" />`, but the same error persisted.

If I wasn't typing a file from an npm module, I would have just put the types in `./node_modules/foo/bar.d.ts`, but I don't want to manually put anything in `node_modules`.

Comment: The ugly solution, but might work - go to the package and check if required types really present. Copy it from there an put to the root of your project named typings.d.ts Into your tsconfig.json add new entry into the types array: "./typings"

Comment: @Drag13 The types I need aren't in the package's types, so that won't work.

Comment: Check  @types/<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME> for types you need. In any case, you need at least some types. Or you have to write your own.

Comment: @Drag13 I'm writing a library that uses some of the package's internal things that aren't meant to be exported, so I wrote my own types for the files that I need.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I put all my types in `./typings` and added this to `scripts` in my `package.json`:

```
"prepare": "for f in typings/**/*; do cp \"$f\" \"node_modules/${f#*/}\"; done"
```